# Bios can't load linux boot usb

Tags: boot, dual-boot, usb, bios

I have an old computer:

- Motherboard: GA-EP35-DS3R
- BIOS: Award Software International, Inc. F1, 13.12.2007
- Procesor: Intel Core 2 Duo E4600

So, I installed Win 7 x64 (USB boot, image has been written via Rufus). Everything worked fine. Next step I decided to install Manjaro. So, load usb has been made the same way like Windows. But it doesn't want to boot. Tried other Linux distros: Ubuntu 18.04, Arch, Mint. The same result: [image]

Comment: F4 2009/06/19 Support Xpress BIOS Rescue function. Can you update your BIOS to Version F4 and See.. http://download.gigabyte.us/FileList/BIOS/motherboard_bios_ga-ep35-ds3r_f4.exe

Comment: To update it, i need to install windows x86, to try to run this update. I tried before (previous system was win7x86), but got errors every time I tried to update :/

Comment: the link generated after selecting Windows7 64Bit in the manufacturer support page. Can you recheck please? As you mentioned you already have Win7 x64 Bit Installed.

Comment: as per the manual of your motherboard `Extract the file and save the new BIOS file (e.g. ep35ds3r.f1) to your floppy disk, USB flash drive, or hard drive. Note: The USB flash drive or hard drive must use FAT32/16/12 file system.` make a USB formatted with the file system mentioned and update your BIOS first.

Comment: is the bootable USB shown in the Boot Menu, when you press F12 Button?

Comment: Ahhhh, ok, I should try. Previous times I updated BIOS in Windows (on my laptop). I will try, and let u know :) Yeah, all bios buttons work correctly

Comment: when you press F12 Button does it show the bootable USB in Boot Menu?

Comment: yes it does. I should update BIOS via boot menu?

Comment: if you downloaded that file.. keep that extracted file like EP35DS3R.F4 in USB Formated to FAT32/16/12 file system then yes via boot menu.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79303/discussion-between-koshachok-and-pratap).